# PHP Admin for Parse.com iOS apps

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, parse-platform

Is it possible to create a web app, that access to a Parse hosted iOS app's database and can write it?

For example, i have an app where users share different content and every content can be marked as spam. If a user marks the content as spam i add it to a Parse class where i store all of the spam contents. I would like to create an "admin" page with php that lets me to check the marked posts and delete them if it's spam.

So i would like to retrieve data from an iOS Parse app, and delete it inside the web browser at myexamplepage.com/admin-to-delete-spam.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an Admin interface using HTML/JavaScript, just look at the [JavaScript section of the documentation](https://www.parse.com/docs/js_guide). Everything (almost) that you can do in iOS is available in JavaScript too.

Personally I like to tie it together with the free parts of [KendoUI](http://www.kendoui.com) to make it easier to build lists and data-bind things.

Comment: Thank you Timothy! Possibly can you tell me about your past experiences? Is it easy like i just make a layout with KendoUI and use the JavaScript API to retrieve and edit the data from Parse? You don't use PHP at all?

Comment: Yes, I'm currently using Parse and KendoUI to plug in dynamic database features to a site who's host doesn't support any server-side code. I simply upload my CSS/JS files and paste a small snippet of HTML to initialise it. If you want me to post some samples, post another question asking how to integrate KendoUI and Parse as it is a more advanced topic.